# Access Webpart properties from a custom class in Kentico

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-parts, kentico

I have a Webpart called OverrideMacros.ascx and a public property called "MetaTagReplace"

```
public partial class CMSWebParts_VLine_Management_OverrideMacros : CMSAbstractWebPart
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    //Swtich to check whether to replace exiting <meta> tags with modified <meta> tags.
    public bool MetaTagReplace { get; set; } 

}
```

I want to access this webpart property "MetaTagReplace" from a custom class placed inside App_Code. How can I achieve that? Following is what I have done so far.

```
    CMSAbstractWebPart overrideMacrosWebPart = RequestStockHelper.GetItem("OverrideMacros") as CMSAbstractWebPart;
  if (overrideMacrosWebPart != null)
    {

    }
```

overrideMacrosWebPart  is always null

Comment: It is not correct from the architecture design stand point to access a property of the web part from another web part, page or class - class inside App_Code can not depend on some web part!

Answer (score 1):

You have to reference the full class name to get access to that property. `CMSWebParts_VLine_Management_OverrideMacros`.  Also the property in your webpart is coded incorrectly. If you want to take advantage of the UI features in Kentico, it should look like this

```
get {return ValidationHelper.GetString(GetValue("PropertyName"), ""); }
```

Maybe [read the Kentico documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/developing-web-parts/working-with-web-part-properties) on developing webparts.